# Can react-native-tvos and react-native co-exist in the same nx monorepo?

Tags: react-native, nomachine-nx, react-native-tvos

I have a NX monorepo used for multiple React and ReactNative applications. I want to include TV support using the react-native-tvos package. I'm unclear about how that package can coexist with the stock react-native package as they both use the same `react-native` node_module folder.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Note: I'm **not** asking for generating a react-native-tvos application using nx. The plan there is to run the create script for TVOS separate and manually migrate the default App into the NX mono-repo (making the standard changes to package.json, tsconfig, etc).

I see a couple possibilities:

1. Just use react-native-tvos across all react-native applications (include mobile only ones)

- Pros:

  - Should *just work*
- Cons:

  - Additional TVOS deps added across all projects
  - tvos update cycle does not always match regular react-native

2. Install react-native-tvos as a local package in a distinct `react-native-tvos` folder. Then use a module resolver to map react-native to react-native-tvos (similar to how react-native-web works).

- Pros:

  - Should work for the JS/TS side
- Cons:

  - Not sure how any native build tooling that relies on node_modules/react-native path existing to be converted to use the tvos folder instead.